# Async function not working when deployed to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, async-await

I have a problem with my Express app (Node.js), when it gets deployed to Heroku. I'm passing an async/await function to my routes from a controller, it works locally on my machine, but it doesn't work when the app gets deployed to Heroku.

Controller:

```
  module.exports = {
     async register (req, res) {
       try {
         const user = await User.findOne({
         username: req.body.username
       })

       if (user) {
         res.status(400).send({
           error: 'error message'
         })
       } else {
         const newUser = await new User({
          username: req.body.username,
          password: req.body.password
       })
        .save()

       const userJson = newUser.toJSON()
       res.send({
         user: newUser,
         token: jwtSignUser(userJson)
       })
      }
     } catch (err) {
       res.status(400).send({
        error: 'error message'
     })
    }
   }
  }
```

Routes:

```
  module.exports = (app) => {
     app.post('/api/register',
       AuthenticationController.register)

     // This does work on Heroku, when async function is run in the route
     app.post('/api/login', async (req, res) => {
       try {
         const user = await User.findOne({
         username: req.body.username
       })

       if (!user) {
         return res.status(403).send({
         error: 'error message'
       })
     }

     const userJson = user.toJSON()
     res.send({
       user: user,
       token: jwtSignUser(userJson)
     })
     } catch (err) {
       res.status(500).send({
       error: 'error message'
     })
    }
  })
 }
```

If the async function gets run directly in the route, as seen with the login route here, it does work on Heroku though.

The only error I get, is the Heroku timeout error, since the request is pending for more than 30 seconds:

```
 2017-11-27T23:45:50.854011+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/api/register" host=pba-bachelor2017.herokuapp.com request_id=485143e5-13b4-4c0e-a2c1-6c137dc6fbd0 fwd="192.38.10.202" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: Adding logging, and fetching those logs from Heroku is going to make a this much more solvable and complete question.

Comment: The problem is that I do not get any other errors than the Heroku timeout error, after the request has been pending for 30 seconds :(

Comment: Does the request get to the route?  Does it have all the correct data? Does it make the request to the db? Does it work if you simply use a promise? Are there any build errors on Heroku deploy?

Comment: The controller doesn't respond at all and there's no build errors on the Heroku deploy. I don't know about the others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

The mongo URI was passed wrong from the heroku env variable with double " in each end.

Answer (score 3):

Node.js started supporting ES7 async/await syntax after 7.x.x versions. The reason might be that your node on heroku instance is 6.x.x version or lower and doesn't read your async/await code correctly.

You can solve this issue by specifying node version on package.json.

```
{
  "name": "your-heroku-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  ...
  "engines": {
    "node": "7.10.0",
    "npm": "4.2.0"
  }
  ...
}
```